# Is there a dilation (along with rigid motion) mapping a given triangle to a similar triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

Suppose we have two triangles ABC and PQR which are similar.

**Does there exist an angle preserving transformation (that preserves incidences and tangencies) that maps A to P, B to Q and C to R? Is it unique?**

I would like to see a reference if the result is standard. Also under what additional conditions is the transformation unique.

Intuitively, it feels like we should be able to rotate/reflect/translate ABC and fit ABC on PQR after dilation.

Answer (score 1):

We can just rigidly move ABC to be in the same orientation of the other triangle, then rigidly move ABC until the centroids match, then dilate by a factor $\alpha$ using the centroid as the center of dilation to make ABC and PQR match. This is basically the definition of similarity.